# Inconsistent Behavior at Rocket Chat REST API call to send Message via C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, rocket.chat

I have created a Rocket Chat server locally (version 2.4.11) and i'm trying to send a message to an user through the REST API.

The program is written in C#, and uses the HttpWebRequest to create each call, then the WebResponse class to receive each response, parsing it's contents (witch are JSON based data, according to Rocket Chat REST API documentation).

My calls are 4 fold, in that order, to:

1 - **LOGIN** ("*api/v1/login*" url, passing as JSON a user and password for the "sender" user)

2 - **IM.CREATE** ("*api/v1/im.create*" url, passing the X-Auth-Token and X-User-Id data at the headers, and the JSON for "username" of the destination account, in order to create - or find - a room id to call the next API with)

3 - **SENDMESSAGE** ("*api/v1/chat.sendMessage*", again with the X-Auth-Token and X-User-Id headers, and a JSON with the Room Id provided by last call, with the message as well)

4 - **LOGOUT** ("*api/v1/logout*", with the user header data to end the connection/session)

When i use my own account (witch was the first account created, with ADMIN role) to send to any other account, it works and the message is sent - every step receives a response according to the documentation and passes to the next call - but when i use a bot account (such as rocket.cat) or even if i use any other account, with user o admin roles (created a new account with ADMIN role to test it) the calls don't work after the IM.CREATE, that returns with no data on the JSON response.

Is there anything that i need to activate when creating a new account to allow it to work (even if the role is ADMIN)? Is that the correct order and API's to use to send a message to a user (not to a group of people, but to 1 person, as an IM)?

**UPDATE**

Posted the issue on GitHub (rocket chat project) on [REST API, Error 400 calling after Login #17334](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/17334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out it was something that i didn't know about causing this error - the recipient address is case-sensitive, and a account name "user" and "User" are not found by the API unless it matches the exact case. Althought it passes on the login API (wich is case-insensitve), the im.create is not, so the sender name doesn't need to mach, but any recipient must.